# SHIR port 443 Occupation

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-synapse, azure-virtual-network

I am running a SHIR that is attached to Azure Synapse on a VM host that uses outbound port 443. I want to create a scheduled custom AzCopy service that also uses outbound port 443 on that same VM. Is this possible if the schedules of the AzCopy service and Synapse jobs don't overlap or does the SHIR occupies port 443 uninterrupted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is an outbound connection, the port is not "held" by self hosted integration runtime, and you can use it with other applications.